# Criação dinâmica de imageview

Tags: android, imageview

Como criar imageviews no android dinamicamente baseados em um resultado de uma busca no banco?
Por exemplo, tenho um produto que sempre vai ter uma imagem.
Mas ele pode ter uma ou duas imagens extras.
Como eu crio um imageview se o resultado das imagens extras for verdadeiro?

Comment: Como você pretende apresentar a imagem para o usuário?

Comment: @CarlosBridi no sqlite eu armazeno um url com o link da imagem e carrego ele com Picasso

Comment: Entendi, você pode usar um esquema de "slider". Essa biblioteca: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider tem um exemplo muito parecido com o seu, também usa o picasso e armazena a URL no SQLite.

Comment: @CarlosBridi bom exemplo, vou usar em outra coisa que estava querendo fazer, mas o que preciso agora é mostrar uma embaixo da outra, pq pego as imagens extras de tabelas diferentes, tem outra descrição, etc